# Integrate custom API authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0

I want to create a webapp using Laravel framework with a sort of custom authentication system.

I 've an external API like this

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/subscribers/v1/?source=XXX&licenseplate=AB123AS
```

and to use this api i need to generate a token that after some period expires.

To generate this token i need to consume this service

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/oauth/v2/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials
```

This Api tells me if the customer is covered or not and has as input parameters: source and license plate.

So my goal is to create a login form with these 2 parameters (source and license plate) input by customer that consume that API and only if it returns covered, customer can access a reserved area  and do some stuff.

How can i do this in Laravel?
I have to create a new service provider, new user model and guard? How? :S or use in some way auth2.0 integration?

Thanks

Comment: Laravel [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) provides a full oauth workflow if that's what you're after.

Comment: I don't know if with OAuth2 I will reach my goal. I just want to do an app with an authentication based on that external API response :S If that external API give me a result user can access protected area if no access denied.

Comment: What is the external service? Surely it has documentation that can be referenced? Can't really advise further without more information.

Comment: usually laravel main authentication is with login / password against a db. Now i have an API like this https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/subscribers/v1/?source=XXX&licenseplate=AB123AS and this return yes or no for example. Can i use this response as a sort of authentication method. Only if this service return yes laravel give me access to protected area...

Comment: It's your application, you can do whatever you want. That doesn't seem particularly secure to me as has the potential for [brute-force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack). Whether that's true and/or an issue will be for you to decide.

Comment: yes also for me is not so secure, but customer doesn't want a registration system :S Anyway if i wanted to develop my idea i have to write custom service provider, user model and guard? Can i just use guzzle two times to consume API and put them in guard ? I dont think it is correct .....

Comment: Sounds to me like the decision has already been made on how this "authentication" should work.

Comment: How can implement in laravel this?

Comment: That's a pretty vague and open-ended question. You've not provided any information on how the `source` or `licenseplate` parameters are processed to determine if they are valid or not. Will require more information such as how you're determining if the request input is acceptable or not.

Comment: source is a 3 digit string code and licenseplate is 5 digit string code and they are parameters of API request. Customer just has to put this parameters in a form and it is the API to retrieve the response (yes or no). I just want to understand how implement this system in laravel. I think i need to use Guzzle to consume this API and put all this somewhere?

Comment: Basic flow would be submit a form in Laravel capturing the `source` and `licenseplate` parameters, then use the [`HTTP Client`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) to call your `API` with the data. Then you can decide what to do based on the response of the API call.

Comment: ah ok so i have not to modify the original laravel authentication system...custom service provider, user model and guard...maybe this is not the case...

Comment: I don't think that is required based on the information you've provided and functionality you've described.

Comment: ok i will read http client explaination that u suggest me . Thanks ;)

Comment: I found that maybe solution to my case is to use Laravel Socialite...so I tried to create customProvider,  but my API doesn't have this https://xxxxxxx/oauth/v2/authorization so I don't know how to change this protected function getAuthUrl($state)